# Terraform private endpoint and subsequent apply results in destroy/recreate

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                 = "example-endpoint"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.id
  target_resource_id   = azurerm_storage_account.example_connect.id
  subresource_name     = "blob"

  depends_on = [azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule.example]
}
```

Question 1# subsequent apply results in destroy/recreate and changing IPaddress. Resulting in production issue?
Question 2# How to auto approve blob storage endpoint ? "Approval State" is set to "Pending"

Comment: Please show what you have tried for the second question. Also please paste the screen shot of approval state is set to pending for blob storage endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1# subsequent apply results in destroy/recreate and changing
> IPaddress. Resulting in production issue?

Subsequent apply for a terraform resource won't destroy and recreate the existince resource. Terraform works on incremental changes.As the configuration changes, Terraform is able to determine what changed and create incremental execution plans

Comment: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/private-endpoint-gets-destroyed-and-recreated-when-terraform-state-file-is-refreshed/33016